# Symfony 4.2 unit testing wont works

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, functional-testing

I am doing unit testing / functional testing, but my code gives me an error. Kindly have a look on my code and suggest a solution.

Codes On Controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;


use App\Entity\Organization;
use App\Entity\User;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Swift_Mailer;
use Swift_Message;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class RegisterController extends AbstractController
{

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Validate the data
     * Encodes the password
     * Creates new organization if evaplyId does not exists
     * Create user and send verification email.
     * return status
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $userPasswordEncoder
     * @param ValidatorInterface $validator
     * @param Swift_Mailer $mailer
     * @return Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $userPasswordEncoder, ValidatorInterface $validator, Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        try {
            $form = $request->getContent();
            $form = json_decode($form);
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //doctrine manager for entity managing
            $user = new User();
            $user->setEmail($form->email);
            if (!$this->checkEmail($form->email)) {
                return new JsonResponse(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Email already exists']);
            }
            $user->setFirstName($form->first_name);
            $user->setLastName($form->last_name);
            $user->setPassword($form->plain_password);
            if (!$form->evaply_id) {
                if(!$form->organization_name)
                    return new JsonResponse(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Missing field Organization']);
                $organization = new Organization();
                $organization->setName($form->organization_name);
                $startGuideStatus['status'] = false;
                $startGuideStatus['add_company'] = false;
                $startGuideStatus['first_connection'] = false;
                $startGuideStatus['first_scorecard'] = false;
                $startGuideStatus['first_order'] = false;
                $organization->setStartGuideStatus(($startGuideStatus));
                $organization->setCustOrSupplier($form->cust_or_supplier);
                $evaply_id = $this->generateEvaplyId($form->organization_name);
                $organization->setEvaplyId($evaply_id);
                $entityManager->persist($organization);
                $entityManager->flush();
            } else {
                $organization = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Organization::class)->findOneBy(array('evaplyId' => $form->evaply_id));
                if (!$organization) {
                    return new JsonResponse(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid Evaply ID']);
                }
            }
            $user->setOrganization($organization);
            $user->setUuid($this->generateUUID());
            $user->setRoles(['Admin']);
            $error = $validator->validate($user);
            if (count($error) > 0) {
                return new JsonResponse(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation error']);
            }
            if ($form->plain_password != $form->confirm_password) {
                return new JsonResponse(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Password miss match']);
            }
            $user->setPassword(
                $userPasswordEncoder->encodePassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->plain_password
                )
            );
            $token = $this->generateVerificationToken($user);
            $this->logger->info($token);
            $verificationUrl = $this->getParameter('app_url') . "account/verify/" . $token;
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->sendUserRegisteredMail($user, $verificationUrl, $mailer);

            return new JsonResponse(['status' => true, 'message' => "Successfully registered"]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
            return new Response($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check email duplication in database
     *
     * @param $email
     * @return bool
     */
    public function checkEmail($email)
    {
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
        if ($user)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    /**
     * Generate a unique id using organization name and timestamp
     *
     * @param $orgName
     * @return string
     */
    public function generateEvaplyId($orgName)
    {
        $org = strtoupper(substr($orgName, 0, 3));
        $dateTime = time();
        $evaply_id = $org . $dateTime;
        return $evaply_id;
    }

    /**
     * Generate unique uuid for user
     * Recursive function
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function generateUUID()
    {
        $uuid = rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(array('uuid' => $uuid));
        if ($user) {
            return $this->generateUUID();
        } else {
            return $uuid;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send email to user after a successfull registartion.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @param Swift_Mailer $mailer
     * @return int
     */
    public function sendUserRegisteredMail(User $user, $verificationUrl, Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $message = (new Swift_Message("Successfully Registered"))
            ->setFrom('admin@evaply.com')
            ->setTo($user->getEmail())
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'emails/registration.html.twig',
                    array('firstName' => $user->getFirstName(), 'lastName' => $user->getLastName(), 'verificationUrl' => $verificationUrl)
                ),
                'text/html'
            );
        return $mailer->send($message);
    }

    /**
     * Generates a verification token using aes-128-gcm encryption
     * encrypts email and uuid
     * encode ciphertext with base64 encoder
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return string
     */
    public function generateVerificationToken(User $user)
    {
        $data = array();
        $data['email'] = $user->getEmail();
        $data['uuid'] = $user->getUuid();
        $plaintext = json_encode($data);
        $cipher = $this->getParameter('cipher');
        if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods())) {

            $this->logger->info("inside cipher");
            //$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
            $iv = $this->getParameter('secretIV');
            $key = $this->getParameter('cipher_key');
            //$tag = $this->getParameter('tagg');
            $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options = 0, $iv);
            $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options = 0, $iv);
            return $token = base64_encode($ciphertext);
        }
    }
}
```

Codes On Tests/Controller Folder

```
   <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: xavier-phases
 * Date: 22/1/19
 * Time: 5:09 PM
 */

namespace App\Tests\Controller;
use App\Controller\RegisterController;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class EvaplyTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testGenerate_evaply_clid(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $id= new RegisterController();
        $org_name=$id->generateEvaplyId('Tset');
        $org = strtoupper(substr($org_name, 0, 3));
        $dateTime = time();
        $evaply_id = $org . $dateTime;
        return $evaply_id;
    }
}`
```

I am calling the `generateEvaplyId()` method from the register controller. I have installed all test packages. It gives me the following error:

```
"ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Tests\Controller\EvaplyTest::testGenerate_evaply_clid(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected".  KIndly have a look and suggest me a solution.
```

Comment: you try to inject `LoggerInterface` to `TestCase`Which are not manage by dependency injection container. Symfony does not know how to deal with it. Is it mandatory for you to have this logger available ? If yes, then you should have look of [lib like this](https://github.com/jakzal/phpunit-injector)

Comment: May you want check this page: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing

Comment: Why does that test method contain a variable in the definition head (which the testrunner will never set), not a single assertion to be checked, and return some ID?

Comment: Hello. The error message is "`Too few arguments to function App\Tests\Controller\EvaplyTest::testGenerate_evaply_clid()`". This means that there are not enough arguments passed to the `testGenerate_evaply_clid`. You need to give the correct arguments to the function. Alternatively, if some of the words are unclear to you, may I suggest you look up their definition to get a better idea?

Comment: @XavierIssac You did try to autowire PHPUnit method and this obviously wont work that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Controller;
use App\Controller\RegisterController;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class EvaplyTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @var LoggerInterface|MockObject */
    protected $logger;
    /** @var RegisterController **/
    protected $controller;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->logger = $this->createMock(LoggerInterface::class);

        $this->controller = new RegisterController(
            $this->logger,
        );

        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testGenerate_evaply_clid()
    {
        $result = $this->controller->generateEvaplyId('Test');
        $this->assertEquals( 'TEST1548303737',$result);


    }
}
```

Here is how it should be. Initiate controller instance and all it's dependencies in `setUp` method, then, in all the tests you can reference them. By default, PHPUnit does not expect any dependencies for tests suite, what you tried to do is called data provider (check for [data providers docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)), it does require additional annotation and used for completely different purpose.

And for the last, I do NOT recommend you to store any part of logic in controllers. Move everything to service layer. Controllers are only to catch request, pass it to manager and return response.

Comment: @XavierIssac No problem:) have a nice day